# "Спор" и "спориться": корень один, значения разные

Tags: однокоренные-слова

"Дело спорится" — работа удается на славу. "Спорить" — препираться, доказывать правоту. Корень один, а значения противоположные. Как так получилось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это разные корни. Спорится-удаётся на славу - от прилагат. СПОРЫИ, спорый - обильный, богатый, удачный.

Спорить, спор-от др.-русск. съпоръ, также соупоръ (из *сѫ-поръ)"ссора, спор, распря". 
После утраты редуцированных внешне корни стали одинаковы,но только внешне, смысл  же разный.